# My post was incorrectly locked

Tags: support

[This post](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/334/my-nose-presses-in-a-lot) has been incorrectly locked: OP was not 12 when posted. The person pictured in the question is 12 - these are two different people, myself and my sister. At the time of posting, I (OP) was 16.

This is clarified (to some extent) in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm tempted to LOL just a bit here. My apologies. Based on your length of participation network-wide it's fairly clear you weren't 12 in 2015, so I'm unlocking the post. Sorry about that, but with the "I am 12" statement in the post I hope you can see why I did so.

Comment: Fully understand. I’m going to edit the post to clarify